# Expandable height gridview horizontal & vertical spacing in orientation changes

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview

I created Expandable height grid view with horizontal vertical spacing & orientation changes.now I facing issue on below image.
[image]

I using column Width for streach mode in grid view.when orientation changes it fit automatically based on both portrait or lanscape.but the the column each item space are different compare to width for each items.how can i set equal space for both width & column on expandable height grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Using resize() in picasso it working perfectly..i tested manully.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getimg()).resize(800,800).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_place_800x800).into(mViewHolder.mIvimage);
```

above code solve my issue using  resize in picasso...